# Change the font size of the data label in geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plotted the following graph, I want to change the font size of the labels for the datapoints.

The second thing is that I would like to shrink the actual plot (the geom_line and geom_point) from the right so that there is a larger gap between the italic annotations and the lines. I dont want to add any space from the left (between the y-axis and the lines). I also would like to keep the dimensions of the plot as I am printing them at 3"x3".

```
> dput(figure2)
structure(list(S = c(9, 12, 15, 9, 12, 15, 9, 12, 15, 9, 12, 
15, 9, 12, 15, 9, 12, 15), UG = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("UG-124", 
"UG-116", "UG-108", "UG-100", "UG-92", "UG-84"), class = "factor"), 
L = c(215, 200, 186, 237, 220, 206, 257, 240, 226, 276, 260, 
243, 297, 280, 263, 318, 300, 283)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))

fontsize3 <- 7.5 / .pt

a <- ggplot(figure2) +
 aes(x = as.factor(S), y = L, colour = UG, group = UG) + geom_line(size = 0.7) +
 geom_point() + geom_text(aes(label = paste0(L,"'")), hjust=0.5,  vjust=-1, size=fontsize3, colour="black") + 
  theme_classic() + scale_color_hue() +
 labs(x = "Girder Spacing (ft)", y = "Max Span Length (ft)", 
  color = element_blank()) + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.08,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(160, 340, by = 50),1),limits = c(180,340)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(0,5,0,0), size=9, colour="black"),
  axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(4,0,0,0),size=9, colour="black"),
  axis.text.y = element_text(size=7, colour="black"), plot.margin = unit(c(0,0.45,0,0), "cm"),
  axis.text.x = element_text(size=7, colour="black"), legend.position="none",
  axis.line = element_line(colour = 'black', size = 0.3), 
  axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.3)) +
  annotate("text", x = 3.295, y= 283, label = "UG-124", size = fontsize3, 
       family = "sans", fontface = 'italic') +
  annotate("text", x = 3.295, y= 263, label = "UG-116", size = fontsize3, 
       family = "sans", fontface = 'italic') +
  annotate("text", x = 3.295, y= 243, label = "UG-108", size = fontsize3, 
       family = "sans", fontface = 'italic') +
  annotate("text", x = 3.295, y= 226, label = "UG-100", size = fontsize3, 
       family = "sans", fontface = 'italic') +
  annotate("text", x = 3.275, y= 206, label = "UG-92", size = fontsize3, 
       family = "sans", fontface = 'italic') +
  annotate("text", x = 3.275, y= 186, label = "UG-84", size = fontsize3, 
       family = "sans", fontface = 'italic') +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

Comment: You have `size=fontsize3` currently. If you want it bigger, change `fontsize3` to be bigger. Or add to it in your `geom_text` layer, `size=fontsize3 + 1`, for example.

Comment: You're also already using `scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.08,0))` - if you want more space on the x scale on the right side, switch to something like `scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.8, 1), add = c(0, 0.2))`

Comment: @GregorThomas I believe the fontsize3 is for the annotations, I want to change the size of the labels, the 200' on top of the datapoints

Comment: Those labels are drawn by the `geom_text()` call. Which has `size = fontsize3` inside it, controlling the size.